# Rails: testing migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, migration

I want to test my migration file. There are two tables: Location and User. Location has_many Users. Tables are connected through location_id. Migration is adding unique constraint to a column "name" in "Location" table and deleting duplicate rows with duplicate location name in the "Location" table and making all the users to point to the first occurence of their location.

This is the part of my migration File :

```
def self.remove_duplications
     grouped = all.group_by{|location| [location.name] }
     grouped.values.each do |duplicates|
       # the first one we want to keep right?
       first_one = duplicates.shift # or pop for last one
       users = User.all
       users.each do |user|
         if user.location && user.location.name == first_one.name
          user.location_id = first_one.id
          user.save!
         end
       end
       duplicates.each do |duplicate| 
         duplicate.destroy!
       end
     end
    end
  end

  def self.up
    Location.remove_duplications
    remove_index :locations, column: :name
    add_index :locations, :name, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :locations, column: :name # remove unique index
    add_index :locations, :name # adds just index, without unique
  end
```

How can I test this? Its getting difficult to test it manually.

Comment: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/01/27/start-testing-your-migrations-right-now/

Comment: I had seen this, but its using Rspec for testing. But I am not using Rspec. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by splitting this into two different migrations:

```
class RemoveDuplicateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # @todo remove duplicate records ...
  end
end

# is not very complex now
class AddNameUniquenessToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :locations, column: :name
    add_index :locations, :name, unique: true
  end
end
```

The reason here is that it will make the logic a lot easier and rollbacks a lot less crazy. Also the `RemoveDuplicateLocations` migration is not really reversible - you can't really recreate those duplicate location records in a rollback (well at least not without resorting to a db backup).

We can then start looking into how to test and implement `RemoveDuplicateLocations`. This is rough outline of how you could test it:

```
require 'test_helper'
require Rails.root.join('db', 'migrate', '20160519121310_remove_duplicate_locations.rb')

class RemoveDuplicateLocationsTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  let(:migration) { RemoveDuplicateLocations } 
  let(:previous_version) { "abc_123" # add previous state here } 

  # you may want to use factories or fixtures here
  let(:locations) do
    [
      Location.create(name: 'Paris')
      Location.create(name: 'Paris')
      Location.create(name: 'London')
    ]
  end
  let(:users) { locations.map.do { |l| User.create(location: l) } }

  def setup
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(['db/migrate'], previous)
    users # insert records by referencing lazy loading let var
  end

  def test_removes_duplicate_records
    migration.up
    duplicated_names = Location.group(:name)
                                 .having("count(name) > 1")
                                 .count.keys
    assert_empty duplicate_names
    assert_equals 2, Location.count
  end

  def test_relinks_user_location 
    migration.up
    users = User.where(location: { name: 'Paris' } )
    asset_equals 2, users.where(location: locations.first).count
    asset_equals 0, users.where.not(location: locations.first).count
  end
end
```

You would then implement the migration:

```
class RemoveDuplicateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    dupe_names = Location.group(:name).having("count(name) > 1").count.keys
    dupe_names.map do |name|
      dupes = Location.where(name: name).order(:id).ids
      first = dupes.shift
      User.where(location_id: dupes).update_all(location_id: first)
      Location.destroy_all(id: dupes)
    end
  end
end
```

This should use far less memory than your attempt since you are not pulling all the locations and users into memory - you may still have issues if the number of locations is extremely large though.

Comment: Note that neither the test nor migration are guaranteed to run! This is meant as a starting point - not a copy paste solution.

Comment: After first migration.up we have to migrate down i guess so that second test can run?  correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(previous)` should reset the the state after each test. If you are using transactional fixtures that should rollback the Location and User records created (I think, I use factories and DatabaseCleaner) otherwise you should clean up in the teardown.

Comment: You may have to dig around a bit to find out how to set the db to the correct state - I would start by learing how ActiveRecord::Migrator works and looking at the rails tests https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activerecord/test/cases/migrator_test.rb

Comment: Thanks a lot man! :) Grabbed few of your ideas. I did it in one single migration. Though its little messy but its one time migration. And the test worked too. :)